# Why is it that some fantasy stories have modern inventions and amenities?

Tags: fantasy-genre

I have noticed that some stories that are fantasy, set in a period where we still fight with swords, people wore dresses, and there are knights, there is a porcelain throne, and a running faucet.  Is this just the author not wanting to give up modern day luxuries or just a part of accepting the fantasy?

Answer (score 3):

None of those are particularly modern, porcelain is over 2000 years old and indoor running water is as much as 5000 years old. The Neolithic skara Brae settlement had indoor toilets in 3000BCE Romans had multistory buildings with faucets and running water on all floors.  Cloth textiles go back even further, sewing needles 19,000 years old have been found.